# RewriteRule not work if file exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Return 404 if REQUEST_URI=/test/123
and file "test" exists

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Part of rewrite.log:

91.201.231.36 - - [22/May/2016:14:03:07 --0400] [new.site.com/sid#b6228858][rid#b6b87058/initial] (4) [perdir /home/www/new.site.com/htdocs/] RewriteCond: input='/home/www/new.site.com/htdocs/test' pattern='!-f' => not-matched

Comment: you don't want any one to request test file or test directory?

Comment: your code will redirect non existing files to index page

Comment: requested file "/test/123" not exist, but exist file "test".
=> and code not work :(

Comment: tell what you need exactly ?

Comment: I need redirect /test/123 to index.php

Comment: solution:
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php